# Not able to add CORS for a particular route in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, cors, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 5 for my app and to set the content-type I used CORS Middleware which looks like this.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With')
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    }
```

This is the function in Class CORS.

But, when I return a Blade view, for example the `auth/login`, I get a plain HTML code in the browser instead of getting the actual view of HTML.

When I change the 'Content-Type' to text/html, the views work, but the apis which return and accept json, doesn't work.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');. This is your error. That line is telling to your browser to display the content as actual JSON and not HTML content. Remove this line, and it's OK

Comment: But, I also need application/json for the apis.

Comment: You have to make another Middleware, and use it in a group wrapping all of your API's routes;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're telling the bowser you're sending json, but actually sending it HTML.

You can get around this by using the following.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $return = $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

    if ($request->wantsJson())
    {
        $return->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }

    return $return;
}
```

By using the `$request->wantsJson()` function you're able to tell if the current request is asking to receive json or not, it does this by checking the accepted content-type header. See: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L581